# Exception handling – final routine for the whole script

Tags: python, exception, try-catch-finally

Another Python question. I'm familiar with the `try – except – finally` concept. 
What I would like to know: is it possible to call some final clean-up routine when the program raises an error, no matter where?
For instance, let's assume my program calls several routines and some of those routines have a try–except statement.

```
def fun_a(x):
    do something
    try:
        something
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e

def fun_b(x):
    do something different
    try:
        something different
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e

fun_a()
fun_b()

# OnError:
finally:
    clean_up(temporary_files)
```

Instead of inserting the same clean-up routine in every try–except scope, I would like to call it at the end of my main script, if there occurred an error somewhere.
Or is the only way to enclose everything in a `main` function and put this again into a try–except–finally block?

Thanks in advance for your help,
Markus

Comment: Take a look at [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html?module-atexit#module-atexit)

Comment: That looks actually exactly like what I was looking for, thanks :-)